# How to show the last row of a query instead of all the rows happened in a duration?

Tags: php, mysql

I use the following query to find who are active in my website (10 seconds) from table `a` and to display the last page (currently in) from table `b`, I put a 5 inutes duration. The problem is that in some cases, if browsing is faster than 5 minutes, it will display more than one page.

What I want is to show the output on a per user basis but also to show only the last opened page.

How to do this?

```
SELECT a.code, b.code, b.page
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.code= b.code
WHERE a.last_active >= NOW( ) - INTERVAL 10 
SECOND AND b.timestamp >= NOW( ) - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE 
ORDER BY b.timestamp DESC
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below will return the last page for each active entry in the last 10 seconds

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT a.code, (SELECT b.page from b where a.code= b.code and b.timestamp >= NOW( ) - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE ORDER BY b.timestamp DESC limit 1) lastPage 
    FROM a
    WHERE a.last_active >= NOW( ) - INTERVAL 10 SECOND
) as sub where sub.lastPage is not null
```

Comment: hi, thank you for this, but there is a problem. A user maybe active in table `a` (checked every 3 seconds) but not browsed for 6 minutes (table `b`). In this case, I get the user that is active, but NULL from page `b`

Comment: So, if a user is in the page, but not browsed for >5 minutes, he/she must not be displayed in the output

Comment: I adjusted the query, I couldn't comment on the answer of Yasen , so edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just join the `a` table only with the corresponding last result in the `b` table. There is no point get `a.code` and `b.code` in your main `SELECT` part as they should be the same. For every record in table `a` that was added within last 10 second you get the related most recent record from table `b` withing the last 5 minutes.

```
SELECT a.code,
(
    SELECT page FROM b
    WHERE b.code = a.code
        AND b.timestamp >= NOW( ) - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
    ORDER BY b.timestamp DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
FROM a
WHERE a.last_active >= NOW( ) - INTERVAL 10
```

Comment: hi, thank you for this, but there is a problem. A user maybe active in table `a` (checked every 3 seconds) but not browsed for 6 minutes (table `b`). In this case, I get the user that is active, but NULL from page `b`

Comment: So, if a user is in the page, but not browsed for >5 minutes, he/she must not be displayed in the output

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'page_visited.page' in 'where clause'

Comment: Now I get Unknown column 'page_visited' in 'where clause'